# PostgreSQL: Purging snapshots

Tags: postgresql

I couldn't find a way in documentation to purge data in theses table (to keep few months)

truncate cascade snapshots table shows:

NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "snap_params"

NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "bl_snaps"

NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "snap_statements"

NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "snap_statements_total"

NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "snap_stat_user_tables"

NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "snap_stat_user_indexes"

NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "snap_stat_user_functions"

NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "snap_statio_user_tables"

NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "snap_statio_user_indexes"

NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "snap_stat_database"

NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "snap_stat_cluster"

Comment: Use `DELETE` rather than `TRUNCATE`. Or, even better, partition the tables.

Comment: i used cascade in new dev environment to see tables involved.
so there's no such thing as AWR retention in oracle.

Comment: You will have to explain what you mean by AWR retention. I thought AWR in Oracle refers to statistics.

Comment: AWR in oracle is the htmt or text report equivalent to what you get with postgre with profile.report (profile is the schema where pg_profile is installed)

retention and snap_interval are controlled through DBA_HIST_WR_CONTROL.

I'm looking for the same thing in postgre without doing it manually.

Comment: Something like a cron job?

Comment: actullay i generate snaphots every hour using crontab.

in source code of snapshot function i found this line

ret := current_setting('pg_profile.retention')::integer

i will look to it in details

Answer (score 1):

You can define extension parameters like any other parameter in postgresql.conf

pg_profile.retention = 7 - Retention time of snapshots in days. Snapshots, aged pg_profile.retention days and more will be automatically deleted on next snapshot() call.

pg_profile.topn = 20 - Number of top objects

https://github.com/zubkov-andrei/pg_profile